# Menu bar with few rows instead of collapse (Bootstrap)

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

Is it possible to create so menu bar with Twitter Bootstrap 3 with buttons and dropdowns:

**On large display**

```
---------------------------------------
btn1 | btn2 | btn3| btn4 | btn5 | btn6| 
---------------------------------------
```

**On middle display**

```
-------------------
btn1 | btn2 | btn3|
-------------------
------------------
btn4 | btn5 | btn6|
-------------------
```

**On small display**

```
------
btn1 |
------
------
btn2 |
------
------
btn3 |
------
------
btn4 |
------
------
btn5 |
------
------
btn6 |
------
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By using media queries, you should be able to set the with to 100% on small screens, 30-33% on medium screens (if you know there always be three), and whatever you need for it to be on big screens.

If you add this .css-line to the parent element - e.g. `ul`.

```
text-align:justify; &:after { content: ''; width: 100%; display: inline-block; }
```

each menu item should align themself as justified.

Here's a quick jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/nMGfT/